# XU connection pool and the Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

In ODM, I configured the size and other properties of the XU connection pool for improved ruleset performance. I am trying to do the same when using the Business Rules service on Bluemix but do not know how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to configure the XU connection pool for the Business Rules service on Bluemix.

However, I am working with an XML XOM, and I found that I could increase the value of the ruleset property xmlDocumentDriverPool.maxSize to configure the size of the execution pool of XML document drivers. The default setting of 1 could cause a performance bottleneck if several clients executed a ruleset concurrently, so I set its value to the number of clients.